# MySql Showing ? for ō character

Tags: mysql

Environment: I am using Windows 11 and `mysql --version` shows:  `Ver 8.0.32 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

have created a database with Mysql Shell like:

```
CREATE DATABASE test_db CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
USE test_db;
```

I then create an example table like:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tbl (
    title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Now when I go to insert some dummy data that has this (I believe Japanese?) character `ō` like the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO test_tbl(title) values('Bashō');
```

It always shows up as ? in the result set.

I've read several similar questions online recommending different collation such as:

```
utf8mb4_general_ci
utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

but none of them work. I still receive a `?`

Comment: You need to use [`NVARCHAR`](https://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/mysql/data-types/nvarchar_n) for UTF-8, not `VARCHAR`.

Comment: What about ```TEXT```? Would that work?

Comment: I tried NVARCHAR (included N' prefix to the string) and TEXT and had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the character set to the table and column :

```
ALTER TABLE test_tbl CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE test_tbl MODIFY title VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Still does not work. Is it possible that copying the character from the web (since I'm not sure how to type it) is having an issue? E.g. I am copying the character briefly when I insert a row via MySql Shell.

Comment: Could be the issue, then you need to mention the encoding using `mysql --default-character-set=utf8`